# Force open a file with the UTF-8 encoding

Tags: sqlite, utf-8

I have a file that contains text. The file is not a text file, it is a SQL file.

I want to open this file with the UTF-8 encoding in order to copy and paste the texts. So far, I'm trying to do it with TeXShop but this app refuses to use the encoding I'm selecting.

Do you know any other software that I could try and use?

Comment: TextEdit maybe?

Comment: Nope it does not work, I guess because the file is not a text file...

Comment: What exactly is a SQL file for you, how was it created in the first place? What is the result of running `file FILENAME` in Terminal?

Comment: It is `SQLite 3.x database`. The file is created by `Core Data`...

Comment: Don't think there is any editor which allows you to edit this in a text like fashion. What exactly do you want accomplish?

Comment: The `persistentStore` is somehow corrupted, I would like to open it (with a text editor) and copy/paste the text datas...

Comment: Hmm, you might get better answers if you ask for help in recovering data from a corrupted SQLite database, without already limiting the tools to text editors.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that BBEdit was made for. http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/

Comment: @Mark BBEdit is the best tool I've found so far. Feel free to make your comment an answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing that BBEdit was made for. BBEdit will open any file and generally do an excellent job of displaying any embedded text. There is even a menu in the bottom control area for every file that allows you to force a particular text encoding. When I first bought BBEdit it was about $130. At its current price of $50 its a steal. I have no affiliation with Barebones Software, except as a satisfied customer.

http://barebones.com/products/bbedit

Comment: TextWrangler can normally do the same thing for free.

Comment: (it worked but not through the menu in the bottom bar)

Comment: @Colas, there is usually more than one way to do it in BBEdit. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @TomGewecke, BBEdit has a new business model. It will be fully functional for 30 days and after that will support a reduced feature set. I expect TextWrangler to go away like "BBEdit Lite" did. See the BBEdit 11.6 release notes, sixth paragraph down. http://www.barebones.com/company/press/bbedit116_pr.html

Answer (score 0):

emacs has a hex editor if you are hardcore enough to edit database like that.
are you sure you want to do that?

UPD: are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259692/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-sqlite3-database ?

A radical answer addressing the root cause (the database corruption)
involves running the database backend in a different address space
than the client app. But that would be an expensive revamp.

Comment: Anyway, the file is corrupted and has 0 record now... But I can still see the data if I open it in a text editor.

Comment: Ok, are you sure an editor, hex, utf-8 or whatever is the right tool for the job? Ain't there a band aid such as an fsck equivalent for sqlite databases?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything but the best I've found so far is `BBedit`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you are doing web why not. it seems to be geared towards that.